# Convert carry-add loop to a map or reduce to one-liner

Tags: python, converting

I want to perform standard additive carry on a vector. The base is a power of 2, so we can swap modulus for bitwise AND.

```
def carry(z,direction='left',word_size=8):
        v = z[:]
        mod = (1<<word_size) - 1
        if direction == 'left': v = v[::-1]
        accum = 0
        for i in xrange(len(v)):
                v[i] += accum
                accum = v[i] >> word_size
                v[i] = v[i] & mod
                print accum,v
        if direction == 'left': v = v[::-1]
        return accum,v
```

Is there any way to make this function even tinier?

Comment: It would be very handy if you include some `assert`s (3 ó 4) so people can test their refactors easily.

Comment: Good point. I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your code has a lot of copying in it. In the default case (where `direction` is `left`) you copy the array three times. This seems like a lot. There are various minor improvements you can make, for example instead of

   ```
   v = v[::-1]
   ```

   you can write

   ```
   v.reverse()
   ```

   which at least re-uses the space in `v`.

   But I think that it would be much better to reorganize the whole program so that you store your bignums the other way round (with the least significant word at the start of the list), so that you can always process them in the convenient direction.
2. The parameters `direction` and `word_size` are part of the description of the data in `z`. So it would make sense to implement this code as a class to keep these values together. And then you could ensure that the digits always go in the convenient direction for your canonicalization algorithm.

   ```
   class Bignum(object):
       def __init__(self, word_size):
           self._word_size = word_size
           self._mod = 2 ** word_size
           self._digits = []

       def canonicalize(self, carry = 0):
           """
           Add `carry` and canonicalize the array of digits so that each
           is less than the modulus.
           """
           assert(carry >= 0)
           for i, d in enumerate(self._digits):
               carry, self._digits[i] = divmod(d + carry, self._mod)
           while carry:
               carry, d = divmod(carry, self._mod)
               self._digits.append(d)
   ```
3. Python already has built-in support for bignums, anyway, so what exactly are you trying to do here that can't be done in vanilla Python?

   Edited to add: I see from your comment that I misunderstood the context in which this function would be used (so always give us the context!). It's still the case that you could implement what you want using Python's built-in bignums, for example if you represented your key as an integer then you could write something like:

   ```
   def fold(key, k, word_size):
       mod = 2 ** (k * word_size)
       accum = 0
       while key:
           key, rem = divmod(key, mod)
           accum += rem
       return accum % mod
   ```

   but if you prefer to represent the key as a list of words, then you could still implement the key-folding operation directly:

   ```py
   from itertools import izip_longest

   class WordArray(object):
       def __init__(self, data = [], word_size = 8):
           self._word_size = word_size
           self._mod = 1 << word_size
           self._data = data

       def fold(self, k):
           """
           Fold array into parts of length k, add them with carry, and return a
           new WordArray. Discard the final carry, if any.
           """
           def folded():
               parts = [xrange(i * k, min((i + 1) * k, len(self._data))) 
                        for i in xrange((len(self._data) + 1) // k)]
               carry = 0
               for ii in izip_longest(*parts, fillvalue = 0):
                   carry, z = divmod(sum(self._data[i] for i in ii) + carry, self._mod)
                   yield z
           return WordArray(list(folded()), self._word_size)
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will make my way through it. Just quickly the objective is not bignum. I fold an array into parts of length k and add these together, but I preserve the length k, so I discard any carry that falls off one end. It's a mixing step in a key scheduling part of a crypto.

Comment: Your approach reminded me of this: http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes 'the signature of *this shouldn't be a class* is that it has two methods, one of which is `__init__`, anytime you see this you should think "hey, maybe I only need that one method!"'

Comment: @Jaime: it should be clear, I hope, that my classes aren't intended to be complete. I believe that the OP has more operations that he hasn't told us about, that in a complete implementation would become methods on these classes. (Do you think I need to explain this point?)

Comment: Had a closer, look @GarethRees -- that's awesome. I really like that. Very concise on the loops in the BigNum class. Looking at the next part now.

Comment: You understood me perfectly on the second part. I am pretty shocked since I gave just a tiny description. That is really clever, too. You are amazing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I generally write `//` for integer (floor) division so that code is portable between Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary remarks :

- Functional idioms and imperative mutations doesn't play well (except when they do. Cf Scala). Here, both FP and Python lovers will likely be lost !
- Since there is exactly 2 possible directions, use a Boolean. It will prevent typo (trying to pass 'Left' for instance).
- Extract the main computation to a dedicated function. First benefice : you won't have to test for direction twice, which is error prone.
- (1st version) : instead of copying + updating via index (awkward), generate a brand new sequence.

That's an interesting question, since it requires both folding (to propagate the carry) and mapping from updated values (to apply `mod`, ie get the less significant bits). 
Since it's not that common, I suggest to stick with a standard Python approach. Don't force an idiom if it obfuscates.

```
def carry_from_left(z, word_size):
   mod = (1<<word_size) - 1
   res = []
   acc = 0
   for a in z :
      tot = a + acc
      res.append(tot & mod)
      acc = tot >> word_size
   return (acc, res)

def carry(z, left_to_right = False, word_size=8):
   if left_to_right :
      return carry_from_left(z, word_size)
   else:
      acc, res = carry_from_left(reversed(z), word_size)
      res.reverse()  #inplace. Nevermind, since it's a brand new list.
      return (acc, res)
```

Now, if this "map+fold" pattern occurs frequently, you can abstract it.

```
def fold_n_map (f, l, acc):
   """ Apply a function (x, acc) -> (y, acc') cumulatively.
       Return a tuple consisting of folded (reduced) acc and list of ys.
       TODO : handle empty sequence, optional initial value, etc,
              in order to mimic 'reduce' interface"""
   res = []
   for x in l :
      y, acc = f(x, acc)
      res.append(y)
   return acc, res

def carry_fold_left(z, word_size):
   mod = (1<<word_size) - 1
   #Nearly a one-liner ! Replace lambda by named function for your Python fellows.
   return fold_n_map(lambda x, acc: ((x+acc) & mod, (x+acc) >> word_size), z, 0)

def carry(z, left_to_right = False, word_size=8):
   #idem
   ...
```

Comment: Cool, I like that. *Especially* the abstraction of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
def carry2(z,direction='left',word_size=8):
        x = z[:]
        v = []
        mod = (1<<word_size) - 1
        if direction == 'left': x.reverse()
        def cu(a,n):
                v.append((a+n)&mod)
                return (a+n) >> word_size
        accum = reduce(cu,x,0)
        if direction == 'left': v.reverse()
        return accum,v
```

Comment: You are clearly stuck in the imperative paradigm, that's why the code is so verbose (and hard to understand). Check http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html and google for "python functional programming".

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting started. My latest code has a lot more generators, lambdas and functional style...but I am just getting started.